# Design Questions

Tags: c#, object

Im building a windows app in c# and I have the following design question :

I have the following object structure : Parent -> Child Collection - > Child - > Grandchild collection -> Grandchild.

The use case requires that I use my Parent object in stages. Eg. Make a new instance of parent. Populate parent and save. At a later stage I would fetch parent and populate the children and save. At a final stage I would then fetch the parent again and populate the grandchildren for the specific child objects and save.

Is this a bad object model? If so, how will it be possible to split this huge object model into smaller models ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this question can only be answered if we know the domain of the problem. A design is (mostly) right or wrong depending on how it fits the situation.

Comment: I agree with Andrew, If the Object Model maps closely to the real world problem then you're on the right track. What I'd like to add is that sometimes this gives you an object model that is not "convenient" to program against. In these cases design patterns are your friend - you can use patterns to expose the model from different perspectives, simplify access to it via use case specific façades, optimise it through lazy loading. You could also decide to sacrifice some mapping of the model to the real world, to make development easier as a last resort (perfect is the enemy of good).

Comment: the key word is "model", its a projection of the real world, not the real world. Some things you'll leave in, some things you'll omitt. You are modelling a real world situation in such a way as its easy to work with, how you define that depends on the situation. The thing to remember is, theres no right or wrong model, but theres also not a single model. Sometimes you need multiple models to achieve what you want